# Proxy Server with Python Twisted

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, twisted

I'm trying to write a proxy server that does a few things:

1. Receive data from client.
2. Validate data.
3. Forward data to server.
4. Receive data from server `immediately` send back to client.

In `node.js` I can do #4 with `server.pipe(client)`. Is there a similar trick in twisted?

What I have:

```
class Player(protocol.Protocol):

    def __init__(self):
        self.server_connection = reactor.connectTCP('192.168.254.101', 1000, GateFactory())
...

class Gate(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, recd):
        print recd
...

class GateFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):

    def buildProtocol(self):
        return Gate()
...

class PlayerFactory(protocol.Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.players = {}

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Player(self.players)

...

reactor.listenTCP(1000, PlayerFactory())
```

### My problem

I forward the data to the server by doing:

```
self.gate_connection.transport.write(packet)
```

But how do I forward the response to the client from:

```
class Gate(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, recd):
        print recd
```

Answer (score 1):

When you construct `GateFactory`, you need to pass it a reference to `self` (the `Player` instance) which `GateFactory` can then pass on to its `Gate` instances when it creates them in `buildProtocol`.

(Also, please consider using [`HostnameEndpoint`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/endpoints.html#endpoint-types-included-with-twisted) rather than `connectTCP` directly.)

Comment: And how should I use it?

Comment: You should use it because it is faster and more flexible.  `HostnameEndpoint` will connect to IPv6 addresses as well as IPv4, and it will properly honor things like round-robin DNS.  `connectTCP` has a specific signature, but if your code takes an endpoint, you can switch it to any other kind of endpoint (TLS, for example, or Tor via txtorcon).

Comment: As for how to use it - the linked documentation provides an example.